# Call Twitter Bootstrap modal() function from Vue.js

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

How can I call Twitter Bootstrap's modal show function from Vue.js.

```
new Vue({
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      $( '#myModal' ).modal('show'); // <-- this doesn't work
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried? What errors are you getting? With the above code, you aren't including jquery anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to call jQuery methods from Vue.js methods.

This jsFiddle demonstrates that.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/mjawaid/zfya92dh/126/][1]
```